# Como Estender/Herdar componente Angular2?

Tags: herança, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

**Dúvida**

Gostaria de criar extensões para alguns componentes já implementados em Angular 2, sem ter que reescreve-los quase que completamente, pois o componente base podia sofre alterações e gostaria que essas alterações fossem refletidas também em seus componentes derivados.

**Exemplo**

**Criei este exemplo simples para tentar expor melhor minha duvida:**

Com o seguinte componente base `app/base-panel.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'base-panel',
    template: '<div class="panel" [style.background-color]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">{{content}}</div>',
    styles: [`
    .panel{
    padding: 50px;
  }
  `]
})
export class BasePanelComponent { 
  
  @Input() content: string;
  
  color: string = "red";
  
  onClick(event){
    console.log("Click color: " + this.color);
  }
}
```

Gostaria de criar um outro componente derivado que alteraria apenas, por exemplo, um comportamento do componente base, no caso do exemplo a cor, `app/my-panel.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {BasePanelComponent} from './base-panel.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-panel',
    template: '<div class="panel" [style.background-color]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">{{content}}</div>',
    styles: [`
    .panel{
    padding: 50px;
  }
  `]
})
export class MyPanelComponent extends BasePanelComponent{
  
  constructor(){
    this.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

[Exemplo completo e funcional no Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWa1JmH7NaSaJffLsl0x?p=preview)

> Obs: Obviamente este exemplo é simples e poderia ser resolvido de outra forma sem necessitar utilizar herança, mas ele tem como finalidade apenas ilustrar o problema real.

**Problema**

Como podem ver na implementação do componente derivado `app/my-panel.component.ts`, grande parte da implementação foi repetida, e o unica parte realmente herdada foi a `class` `BasePanelComponent`, mas o `@Component` teve que ser basicamente repetido completamente, e não apenas as partes alteradas, como `o selector: 'my-panel'`.

**Pergunta**

A alguma forma de fazer uma herança literalmente completa de um componente Angular2, herdando as definições da `class` e das marcações/anotações, como por exemplo o `@Component`?

**Edit 1 - Solicitação de recurso**

> Solicitação de funcionalidade adicionada ao projeto do angular2 no GitHub: [Extend/Inherit angular2 components annotations #7968](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968)

**Edit 2 - Solicitação Fechada**

> A solicitação foi fechada, [por esse motivo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968#issuecomment-219865739), que resumidamente seria não saber como será feita a mesclagem dos decorator. Nos deixando sem opções. Então minha opinião é [está citada na Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968#issuecomment-222496110), que em português seria algo como:
>
> "Se **Decorator/Annotation** tem essas limitações, que segundo seus argumentos não pode ser facilmente contornadas na biblioteca, lhe faço um questionamento: **Por que utiliza-los?** Será que não seria uma melhor opção ignora-las/descarta-las para o desenvolvimento uma biblioteca do tamanho e complexidade do angular2? Ou pretendente investir tempo/dinheiro em uma biblioteca com limitações primarias como a listada nesta issue? Acredito que este ainda é o momento para grandes mudanças que podem alterar o rumo de angular2, pois a biblioteca ainda esta em RC1. Seria extremamente decepcionante ver uma versão estável de uma biblioteca como angular2 ser lançada com esse tipo de limitação.".

Comment: Se entendi bem sua dúvida você gostaria de ter um `Component` _child_ (podendo ter mais de um `Component` _child_ dentro de um mesmo `Component` _parent_), digamos assim, que consiga alterar alguma propriedade de seu `Component` parent (1 `Component` _parent_ para muitos `Component`_child_). Seria isso?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, é se entendi seu questionamento acho que é quase isso! Resumidamente, gostaria do real efeito de herança para os componentes!

Answer (score 1):

não faz muito sentido herdar a classe de componentes, se entendi bem o que você deseja fazer é reutilização de componentes, se for isso é simples fazer, basta imaginar que você está no HTML e fazer um bind na propriedade que foi criada no component pai, veja esta aula de Loiane Groiner ela explica exatamente isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbSmzblc-qY

Espero ter ajudado.

Um Abraço.

Comment: Faz muito sentido herdar componente, se você tem um componente seu ou principalmente de terceiro, que deseja criar outros com apenas algumas alterações de funcionalidades. Como por exemplo, você tem um componente de terceiro de gráfico de barras e esse não espoe um método de refresh dos dados, só disponibilizando internamente. Então você pode herdar esse componente e expor esse método para uso externo. Isso é só um exemplo simples, mas em meus casos reais há  outras aplicações mais complexas.

Comment: Então, meu caro eu entendo seu ponto de vista porém uma herança é uma especialização de uma classe pai, ou seja ela é a classe pai mais especializada tanto que é possível morfar de uma pra outra, por outro lado o template não sofre herança, sendo assim o mesmo deve ser +/-repetido na herança ou composto quando se usa reutilização/composição de outros componentes, por isso eu disse que não faz muito sentido herdar e sim reutilizar fazendo composição. por outro lado você pode utilizar o **HTML template file** assim você não irá necessitar reescrever o template.

Comment: Correto, isso é verdade para alguns casos, mas se você está utilizando componentes de terceiros, nem sempre o componente foi desenvolvido possibilitando composição, muitas vezes o que você quer alterar não está exposto através de composição e herança é a unica alternativa (ou senão um copy/paste, que seria algo muito ruim pois te dificultaria manter compatibilidade com versões posteriores do componente). E o caso do HTML template file para componentes de terceiros você não tem acesso a referenciar esses arquivos e mutas vezes os componentes de terceiros nem utilizam esse mecanismo.

Answer (score 0):

Tem como você ter uma class abstrata que seria essa classe base. Ela nem precisa ser necessariamente um componente mas consegue implementar lifecycles como init e tal. aí dentro dela você consegue ter comportamentos comuns que vc gostaria de replicar nas classes filhas além de comportamentos especificos adicionais. No entanto vc não consegue estender a anotation component. Além disso vc consegue usar o mesmo css se importar do mesmo arquivo mas o html é ideal cada um ter o seu.

segue um diagrama mais ou menos de como seria:

```
                             UsersListBaseComponent
                             /                    \
                            /                      \
                UsersListMobileComponent        UsersListDesktpComponent
```

Classes:

```
export abstract class UsersListBaseComponent implements onInit { 

  @Input() content: string; //funciona

  userList$: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private userService:UserService){ // vc consegue ter depedencias
 }

 ngOnInit(){
    this.userList$ = this.userService.pegarUsers(); // vc consegue setar atributos
 }

  funcaoComum(event){
  //essa funcao fica disponivel para as classes que herdarem;
  }
}
```

Classe filha

```
export abstract class UsersListMobileComponent implements onInit { 

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private bananaService:BananaService){ // vc consegue ter depedencias extras
    super(userService)//passar Depedencias
  }

 ngOnInit(){
    super.ngOnInit();
 }

  funcaoEspecifica(event){
  //essa funcao fica disponivel somente para a classe filha
  }
}
```